# Autohotkey - I had a problem writing code with WinActive and Hotstring

Tags: autohotkey

I needed code to enable Hotstring when Notepad is turned on and disable Hotstring when Notepad is off. So I wrote the code below, and I found that this code sometimes misses the event that the notepad turns on. How can I fix it?

```
while True
{
    begin:
    Sleep, 1
    ;Untitled - Notepad
    while not WinActive("Untitled - Notepad")
    {
        Sleep, 1
        if WinActive("Untitled - Notepad")
        {
            MsgBox WinActive
            HotString("::hello", "Hello World", On)
            
            goto, begin
    }
    HotString("::hello", "Hello World", Off)
    }
}

a::
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#Directives are meant for this, more specifically the [`#IfWinActive` directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).
Here's your finished product:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
::hello::Hello World
#IfWinActive
```

And `ahk_class` is used for convenience. You can read more about it [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_class).
Alternatively e.g `#IfWinActive, ahk_exe notepad.exe` could be used as well.
Or of course, just a normal `#IfWinActive, Untitled - Notepad` would work as well, but only when you're editing a document named "Untitled". So that's why it's not a good approach.

Comment: ;I eventually wanted code like this.\n
Hotkey, IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad\n
Hotstring("::hello", "Hello World")\n
Hotkey, IfWinActive

Answer (score 0):

AHKv1:

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class Notepad")
::hello::Hello World
#If
```

AHKv2:

```
#HotIf WinActive("ahk_class Notepad")
::hello::Hello World
#HotIf
```

Comment: For some reason, I like this code more! and What's the Difference between #If vs. #HotIf

Comment: Wow Has AutoHotkey v2 been released? thank you for telling me.

Comment: @김형우 it's in alpha and has been for quite a few years. And the code above is not the recommended approach for AHK v1. You most definitely shouldn't use `#If` unless you actually require it.

Comment: @0x464e When I tried using the #If, #IfWinActive yesterday evening, I felt uncomfortable. So, while browsing the Internet, I found out that hotkey also has the same function. "Hotkey, IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad" Shouldn't this phrase be used if possible?

Comment: The [hotkey command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) is used if you need to create/modify hotkeys during runtime. Otherwise there's no need to use it, or benefit from using it.

Comment: @김형우 The best option for creating AHKv1 hotkeys is to use the #If directive as shown in the example. There are several reasons for this. First, it'll be easier to make your code compatible with AHKv2 as you'll only have to replace "#If" with "#HotIf" and you're done; but if you choose to use "#IfWinActive" you'll have additional work to do because there's not a compatible equivalent in AHKv2. Second, the #If directive allows AND/OR/NOT comparisons that are not allowed with "#IfWinActive" or "IfWinActive", like: #If WinActive("ahk_class Progman") Or WinActive("ahk_class WorkerW").